# T-SQL Return Next Weeks Dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, range

I have a table the returns calander information:

[image]

I'm trying to retrn NEXT week Monday thru Friday dates no matter what day it is THIS week.

For example:

Today's Date = 5/21/18 Return 5/28/18 Thru 6/1/18

Today's Date = 5/22/18 Return 5/28/18 Thru 6/1/18

Today's Date = 5/23/18 Return 5/28/18 Thru 6/1/18

Today's Date = 5/24/18 Return 5/28/18 Thru 6/1/18

[image]

This is what I currently have:

```
DECLARE @Date datetime
SET @Date = '5/23/18'

SELECT *, CASE WHEN date = @Date THEN (week + 1) END
FROM Calendar
WHERE  CASE WHEN date = @Date THEN (week + 1) END
```

Is there a way to return the dates for next week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this query.

**Explain**

**1900/01/01** is Monday so you can do.

- `DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, dt) + 1, 0)` let `date` subtract from *1900/01/01* then add one to be next week.
- `DATEADD(day,4,DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, dt) + 1, 0))` use `DATEADD` function to add 4 day from next Monday.

like this.

```
SELECT DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, dt) + 1, 0) AS nextMon
, DATEADD(day,4,DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, dt) + 1, 0)) AS nextFri
FROM T
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cec27/1*

Answer (score 2):

If you're up for a little math, then you could use the [datepart()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) function. Passing the value `dw` as the first argument will return you the day of the week.

`select datepart('dw','2018-05-21');` will return '2' for Monday, because Sunday is treated as the first day of the week.

Using this as a base I came up with the following.

#### Solution

```
declare @d date = GETDATE();
select  @d as 'Date',
    DATEADD(d, 9-DATEPART(dw,@d) + (1-(DATEPART(dw,@d)+5)/7)*-7, @d) as 'NextMonday',
    DATEADD(d,13-DATEPART(dw,@d) + (1-(DATEPART(dw,@d)+5)/7)*-7, @d) as 'NextFriday';
```

#### Explanation

So the idea is to calculate the number of days till the next Monday from the current day of the week. So `Mon=2 -> +7 days`, `Tue=3 -> +6 days`, etc. The number of days to add can be calculated by:

1. Taking a week (7 days, but monday=2, so 7+2=`9`)
2. Substracting from that the day of the week `-DATEPART(dw,@d)`

If Monday was the first day of the week, this would be it. Applying the above on a sunday will add 8 days instead of the desired 1 day. This can easily be corrected by substracting 7 days, but that must only occur on Sundays.

3. Sunday is the first day of the week, so `1`
4. A function that returns '1' on a sunday and '0' on all other days is `(DATEPART(dw,@d)+5)/7` by using an integer division
5. Subtracting those gives '1' on Sundays and '0' on all other days
6. Multiplying that by `-7` turns `+0 days` into `-7 days` just on Sundays

Put all that together and you have a formula to get the next Monday. The next Friday is just 5 days further, so the `9` at the start of the formula turns into `13`.

To see this in action (with intermediate results): [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f84db/1/0)